# AWS OpsWorks - Linux drive to S3 Bucket

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

What would be the best way to 'symlink' pe-say a drive on an AWS linux instance to an S3 bucket?

Currently I am utilizing Apache's ProxyPass to reverse proxy /images/ over to the S3 bucket with the following code.

```
  ProxyRequests Off

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /images/ http://s3bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

This works great, but only for HTTP access through Apache. If I want to write to the /images/ directory from PHP itself, it gets written locally.

So I'm looking for a great way to have /images/ redirected to the S3 bucket for all types of operations. I've looked at S3FS but I'm leary of going that route.

I am also utilizing OpsWorks to work with my EC2 instances so whatever method I go with needs to be able to be automated by OpsWorks and/or Chef recipes.

Another option looked at was the AWS SDK for PHP. This may require me to change the PHP code that would do the file writing to the /images/ directory. This may be the solution in the long run, but for now I need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

While s3fs can sort of fake mapping to s3, you are going to run into problems. The issue is that S3 is not at all like a disk volume.

With a disk volume, you can write and read from the disk in blocks. You can also lock files among other operations.

S3 on the other hand, is an object storage system. It operates on whole files.

S3FS sort of makes it work, but copying the file into your temp directory, so you can write to it, and then copies it back to S3 after you are done.

Simple operations may work ok, such as reading or writing an entire file at a time, but anything that works on block level may fail.

I do recommend updating your PHP code, with the existing clients provided by amazon, its quite easy to do. Instead of `move_uploaded_file`, you would use the client code instead.